# FB Pixel Purchase Event - Pixel activating by fake purchases

Tags: javascript, facebook, shopify

My pixel is being activated by users who see my ad and I found out that they use the javascript code in the search bar and end up activating my purchase pixel (to show more ads to it), is there any way to block this script? This is bothering me a lot, my metrics are getting horrible. Is there any solution for this?

This code

```
javascript:(function(){ var codigo = document.getElementById("ProductJson-product-template"); if(codigo == undefined){ content_id = meta["product"]["id"]; } else { var content_id = JSON.parse(codigo.text)["id"].toString(); } fbq('track', 'Purchase', { content_type: 'product_group', content_ids: '[' + content_id + ']' , value: 99.00, num_items: 1, currency: 'USD', }); console.log("O pixel de PUR foi ativado com sucesso para o content ID: " + content_id); })();
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by _“use the javascript code in the search bar”_? Are you actually talking about the browser console … or does the search field inside your page have a XSS vulnerability?

Comment: https://youtu.be/EmFark_jiYU

Comment: That's what happens, with this script activates my purchase and ends up marking fake purchases, any ideas to block this script ?